# R: Pass a List of Functions into another Function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Is there a way of passing a list of custom functions, into the arguments of another function? A toy example with mtcars, would be to round the figures up, down and to the nearest five, then join them together within the one data frame using a single function, so that:

**mtcars1**

[image]

```
# round_any not in dplyr
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)

mtcars1 <- mtcars %>%
      slice(1) %>%
      select(2:7)
```

is transformed into:

**cars**

[image]

```
# Rounding Functions
round_up_decimal <- function(x) {
  round_any(x, 1, ceiling)
}

round_down_decimal <- function(x) {
  round_any(x, 1, floor)
}

round_nearest_five <- function(x) {
  round_any(x, 5)
}

# Not being used
rn_fun_list = ls(pattern = ("round_"))

new_value_gen <- function(x,y) {
  x %>%
    mutate_all(., y)  
}


mtcars2 <- new_value_gen(mtcars1, round_up_decimal)
mtcars3 <- new_value_gen(mtcars1, round_down_decimal)
mtcars4 <- new_value_gen(mtcars1, round_nearest_five)

cars <- mget(ls(pattern = "mtcars\\d$")) %>%
  map_df(I, .id = "src") %>%
  select(-1)
```

This can be done by calling the `new_value_gen` function manually each time, but it doesn't really follow *DRY* principles. Is there a more elegant way of doing this by passing the `rn_fun_list` into it with one function?

Comment: For readability, as the code was already quite long, I used one row in `mtcars`, so that there were four rows in cars  instead of eight in `cars` table image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `map`

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(rn_fun_list, new_value_gen, x = mtcars1)
```

Answer (score 2):

We could simply use `sapply`:

```
t(sapply(rn_fun_list, new_value_gen, x = mtcars1))
#                    cyl disp hp  drat wt qsec
# round_down_decimal 6   160  110 3    2  16  
# round_nearest_five 5   160  110 5    5  15  
# round_up_decimal   6   160  110 4    3  17
```

If you want to also keep the original line, then, e.g.,

```
t(sapply(c("identity", rn_fun_list), new_value_gen, x = mtcars1))
#                    cyl disp hp  drat wt   qsec 
# identity           6   160  110 3.9  2.62 16.46
# round_down_decimal 6   160  110 3    2    16   
# round_nearest_five 5   160  110 5    5    15   
# round_up_decimal   6   160  110 4    3    17
```